# Fastest way to make a HTTP/HTTPS Call

Tags: java, apache, rest, http, https

I've written some generic code, that is calling any rest service with many customization about http/https request and parameters. Now i'm wondering what is the fastest way/method/code block to call an rest service ?
Right now i'm using Apaches [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/index.html)  with [HttpRequestBase](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) and an average time to get response is about 130 ms (tested on 1000 requests).
I would really love to get below 100 ms per request, any advices ?

### Notes:

I'm already using headers on client level like :
connection : keep-alive , http.connection.stalecheck : true , http.protocol.expect-continue : true and more, but there is almost no change in time of execution. The average time i mentioned earlier is time measured for :

```
responseEntity = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

Which is basically execute of an http request.

Thank You all in advance!
Cheers

Comment: How do you know it's not the responding side which is slow?

Comment: Technically, using soapUI i could get an answer in like 60-90 ms. 
I don't have as much time i would wish to test all other posibilities like Spring RestTemplate and many more that i could find by google ;)

Comment: Are you also testing a thousand requests via SoapUI? Or maybe just one?

Comment: Also 1k requests and as far as i know soapUI is also using Apache libraries...

Comment: You can't get below 100ms per request unless the server can fulfil requests that fast, or faster. The choice of client code or client library is highly unlikely to have any influence on that.

Comment: So how do You explain that, soupUI can get an answer below 100ms, same as Chromes Poster plug-in ? I want to achieve their response time ;)